# Восстановить пароль WP зная соли

Tags: wordpress

Стала задача: нужно перенести пользователей сайта на новый сайт. Старый сайт написан на WP, новый на Yii2. Столкнулся с проблемой: а как узнать пароль пользователя, что бы им их заново не создавать? Я не сильно знаю WP, поэтому интересует есть ли вообще такая возможность

Comment: Невозможно. Там хэш bcrypt.

Comment: а как вообще wp создает хэш? можно его как то воссоздать, зная соль?

Comment: Можно попробовать перебрать варианты, если есть суперкомпьютер и пара столетий времени))

Comment: Забудьте вы эту идею. Алгоритмы шифрования для того и придуманы, чтобы предотвратить подобные попытки)

Comment: я не хочу его взломать, мне нужно понять как создается хэш. что бы я мог создать хэш у себя, записать его в базу Wp и он бы работал, то есть пользователь смог бы пройти авторизацию

Comment: Пароль пользователя узнать нельзя. Почитать о хешировании WP можно здесь https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_hash_password

Comment: извините, если туплю, но я все же опишу вариант: я сохраню себе старые хэши, для таких пользователей создам метку wp. когда он будет входить, я хочу сверять хэш не с хэшом yii2, а со сохраненным хэшом wp. для этого, как я понимаю, мне надо знать, как создать такой хэш. такое возможно или нет?

Comment: Я вас понял, и дал ссылку выше.

Comment: мне хэш надо создавать на сайте, который написан на yii2. а вы скинули ссылку на функцию, которая есть в WP

Comment: Вы чего от меня хотите? Чтобы я за вас встроил эту функцию в yii2?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84672/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-diefair).

Comment: В корне неправильный подход!! Юзерам нужно дать возможность самим перегенерить пароли, а не делать это за них. А предварительно сообщить им (по мылу и через интерфейс ВП в тч) о грядущей смене и чтобы они проверили работоспособность мыла.    Ида узнать пароль в ВП невозможно.